# How to clear the terminal in Py-charm. (non-manually)

Tags: python

I need to clear the terminal in Pycharm without clicking the trashbin myself. I've tried using the whole os and csl thing but it only makes some weird arrow in the terminal.

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: Do you want to clean it on code re-run?

Comment: Write a little Autoitscript :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `os.system` command cannot work because it only executes commands in the Console. It won't work in many other places including IDLE's Python Shell, PyCharm, etc.

It should work in your Terminal. You can write your code in PyCharm and execute it in a terminal.

You can also use multiple `\n`, but it is not really what you want.

Another idea would be to add a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Preferences, look for "clear all" and assign a Keyboard Shotcut, for example I put Ctrl+Alt+5 :

[Keyboard Shotcut, Ctrl+Alt+5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAyLT.png)

Then you need to use it when you are inside the console,

I hope it helps,

Kind Regards,
Manuel.